# Multi Select in IE - item is selected, but not highlighted/registering with validation

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am selecting an item in jQuery from my select like this:

```
$('#myDdl option[value="2"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

It then appears just fine *if* I inspect code (IE 10):

```
<select name="myDdl" id="myDdl" multiple="multiple" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required">
    <option value="1">bla2</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">bla2</option>
</select>
```

So it *appears* that it is working just fine.  But if I look in the browser itself, it is not highlighted.  Also, if I try to submit, I get the validation error that it is Required, hence not selected.  If I bypass validation, the POST even shows empty as well for this element.  This only happens in IE, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
    <select name="myDdl" id="myDdl" multiple="multiple" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required">
        <option value="1">bla1</option>
        <option value="2">bla2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit" />
    <form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('#form').submit(function (event) {
    alert($('#myDdl').val());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I won't have the index, this is just a simplified version.   I will always have the value though.

Comment: Ah - sorry, didn't see it was a mulit-select. This will alert the value - you can check against that.

Otherwise, could it be the (lack) of support for the data-* attribute in IE10 causing problems?

Comment: I ended up using your pre-edit to figure out a work-around.  Selecting by .selectedIndex worked.  In this case I only needed one, so that will do.